# How to automagically assign weight to a Zend Tag Cloud?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, tag-cloud, zend-tag

In the Zend Framework is a very nice and easy way to create a Tag cloud, but the documentation gives no clue about a way to automagically give every tag a weight.
Is there a way to do this? If no, how could it best be done?

Answer (score 0):

The [Zend Tag Cloud](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tag.cloud.html) code example seems to indicate that weight is set the tag array

Comment: As I understand it right, I have to set the weight manually in the array, no?